# Windows extract all matches

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this batch script that runs through 4 different text files (IMSI1.txt IMSI2.txt etc.) , searches for -imsi in them and output the value next to it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=4
for /L %%r in (1,1,%N%) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"-imsi" IMSI%%r.txt') do set line=%%a
   for /F %%a in ("!line:*-imsi=!") do echo %%a>> out & echo %%a> N%%r.txt
)
```

Example

```
Hello this is the text file
asdasd -imsi 367
asdasd -imsi 888
```

**Output**

```
888
```

**Desired Output**

```
367
888
```

How can i fix the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=1
for /L %%r in (1,1,%N%) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"-imsi" IMSI%%r.txt') do (
    set line=%%a
    for /F %%a in ("!line:*-imsi=!") do echo %%a>> out & echo %%a> N%%r.txt
  )
)
```

Comment: worked good, i added >> instead of > in the output too so it appends , thanks